# why is my Edit text not centered in a relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

In my android layout I'm trying to put the edit text in the center of its

parent (relative layout).

But today it leans to right.

[image]

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inputBox"
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="-   -   -   -"
            android:textColor="#00bcfe"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" >
        </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no need to use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` together. Because second one already provides the first one.

Comment: Also instead of `android:text="-   -   -   -"` you can use `android:hint="-   -   -   -"`.

Comment: @BatuhanC thanks. Will it remove the hint one character by another? meaning 4  -  -  -  and then 4  5 -  - and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set `gravity` in your parent `RelativeLayout`? If yes, then remove it. Possibly, it is causing problem.

Comment: why is that? so thumb rule is using android:layout_centerInParent in all children instead of gravity center in their relative layout parent?

Comment: No, it's not.. Depends on the use case. The thumb rule is flow of order should be oneway. Either from child-to-parent or parent-to-child. But not both. Gives you unexpected layout design.

Comment: Specially, when the parent is a RelativeLayout

Comment: i thought it should save repeating the layou_gravity in each child.

Comment: why "specially"? other cases?

Comment: A FrameLayout or a TableLayout

Comment: In case of LL, you do not get Anchors to addRule in the layoutParams of any childView.

Answer (score 1):

check `style="@style/textOnBg"` may be at there you have set margin for EditText.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="-   -   -   -"
        android:textColor="#00bcfe"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" >
    </EditText>
```

Comment: I have removed unnecessary attributes android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" just the following attribute is enough to center allign in Relative layout android:layout_centerInParent="true"